# Using Unreal Macros in own custom Source Files with or without "generated.h"

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

Hello dear Community!

I have copypasted my own source files I wrote outside of Unreal into the "private" (for cpp-files) and the "public" (for my header files) folders of an unreal-C++-Project, so I can include my own custom classes in my unreal source files.

It works as it should, but I want to use my own enums, that are obviously defined in my own non-Unreal-specific Files, as UEnums, so I have to modify them there with Unreal-specific Macros.

Will Unreal Header Tool incorporate my own Files or only the ones I created from the Unreal Editor?
And do I need to write a "...generated.h"-include in my own custom headers I wrote outside of Unreal?

Thank you so much in advance!

I did this:

- first I added a generated.h. My File is named like "File.h", and I added a generated.h-include in it like this:

```
#include "File.generated.h"
```

Of course as the last include, as it should be.

- Then I added the Unreal-Macros to the enum. It went from this:

```
enum MyEnum {
    FIRST_ENTRY,
    SECOND_ENTRY
};
```

to this:

```
UENUM(BlueprintType, Category="Enums")
enum MyEnum {
    FIRST_ENTRY UMETA(DisplayName="First Entry"),
    SECOND_ENTRY UMETA(DisplayName="Second Entry")
};
```

- Then I tried to incorporate a variable with this Enum type as a UProperty in one of my Unreal-Classes like this:

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
    TEnumAsByte<MyEnum> EnumVariable;
```

Sadly I get an Error:

"Error: Expected the name of a previously defined enum"

Of course I included the Header File with my Enum before, so this cannot be the reason I guess.

Comment: please read about [mcve]

Comment: It is in an Unreal-C++-Project, and of course I am depending on Unreals API and Unreal Header Tool, how would someone try to reproduce my Problem?

I am hoping for people who had run in the same problem to share their knowledge.

Comment: i am not familiar with unreal. Though rather than explaining how your code looks like ("Of course I included the Header File with my Enum before,..") it is better to show the code. Also the error message looks incomplete

Comment: Exactly, the first half of the Error message consists of the path to the file and the line. 
Sadly I cannot share the files themselves for copyright reasons.

Comment: "Sadly I cannot share the files themselves for copyright reasons." and thats exactly where the MRE comes in. Its code that you can share, because it has nothing about copyright, but all about the same issue as your actual code.

Comment: But thank you for your will to help, I appreciate that! Maybe someone else sees this question with a little knowledge about Unreal, it seems to be a pretty basic problem.

Comment: @Skyseed Windows or MacOS?

Comment: I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution is the same for UE4 and UE5. These files can be created automatically by running the `GenerateProjectFiles` script to generate new project files:

```
~/UnrealEngine4.27/UnrealEngine-4.27.2-release/GenerateProjectFiles.sh ~/Documents/Unreal\ Projects/TestProject/TestProject.uproject -Game
```

On Windows the script would be in a different location, of course, and you would have to run the `.bat` version.

Anyway, [here is the official documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/how-to-generate-unreal-engine-project-files-for-your-ide/).